# Iterating ExcelFile sheets with sheet_name only giving first sheet?

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to loop through and excel file with 10 sheets and put them all into one data frame. I’m primarily using the code found at [Data Camp.](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/importing-managing-financial-data-in-python/importing-stock-listing-data-from-excel?ex=11)

For whatever reason when I replicate this it just iterates my first sheet 10 times. I’ve also tried using sheet_names as a range from 0-Len sheet names in the case it was a read issue. Does anyone see something wrong with the code?

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(SEC_EXP_PATH)

#The SEC Expense output is spread across a number of sheets. This iterates through them and makes a dataframe for each one.
sheets=range(0,len(excel_file.sheet_names))
sec_expenses=[]
for sheet in sheets:
    expense_sheet=pd.read_excel(SEC_EXP_PATH,sheet_name=sheet, header=1,skipfooter=1)
    sec_expenses.append(expense_sheet)

#combines all of the separate expense dataframes into 1
secexp_df=pd.concat(sec_expenses)
```

Comment: It would help if you added your code to your question.

Comment: reelated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17720996/1240268

Comment: I did a little reading and I’ll check my pandas version. Looks like their was possibly a syntax change from sheetnames to sheet_names. Possibly I have an older version of pandas installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer. Older versions of pandas appear to use the parameter sheetnames. Because of the kwargs allowed, passing sheet_name wasn’t flagging an error but it wasn’t acting as expected either. Updating to newer pandas version resolved

Answer (score 0):

should this

```
expense_sheet=pd.read_excel(SEC_EXP_PATH,sheet_name=sheet, header=1,skipfooter=1)
```

say this?

```
expense_sheet=pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name=sheet, header=1,skipfooter=1
```

Comment: It really shouldn’t matter no?

Comment: You could also try
`dict_of_dfs = excel_file.parse(range(10))`
which should create a dictionary of dataframes with one key-value pair for each sheet

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a better way to loop over the sheets on an excel file:

Pass `sheet_name=None` to `read_csv`. You will get a dictionary where the keys are the sheet names and the values are dataframes:

```
sheets = pd.read_excel(SEC_EXP_PATH, sheet_name=None, header=1, skipfooter=1)

for sheet_name, data in list(sheets.items())[:10]:
    sec_expenses = sec_expenses.append(data)
```